# Question regarding inverse of composite mapping

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have come across a question regarding composite mapping and I have been successful at proving it but I doubt that my proof is formal.

The question is as follows-

> If $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$ be two bijective mapping and let $f^{-1} : Y \to X$ and $g^{-1} : Z \to Y$ be their inverse mapping respectively. Then prove that the inverse of mapping  $g \circ f : X \to Z$ is the map $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1} : X \to Z$.

My proof is as follows-

> Given that the inverse map of $f : X \to Y$ is $f^{-1} : Y \to X$ given by $f^{-1}(Y) = X$, i.e., the inverse inverse image of $Y $ under $f $ is $X $. Also, the inverse map of $g : Y \to Z$ is $g^{-1} : Z \to Y$ given by $g^{-1}(Z) = Y$, i.e., the inverse inverse image of $Z$ under $f$ is $Y$.
>
> Now, 
>   $f^{-1}(Y) = X \implies  f^{-1}(g^{-1}(Z)) = X \implies 
> (f^{-1} \circ g^{-1})Z = X$
>
> i.e. the inverse image of $Z $ under $g \circ f $ is $X $. $\{\text {as, the image of}  X  \text {under $g \circ f$ is}  Z \} $.
>
> Thus the map which is defined by $(f^{-1} \circ g^{-1})Z = X$ is $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1} : X \to Z$.
>
> Hence, the inverse map of $g \circ f : X \to Z$ is the map $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1} : X \to Z$.

Is my proof correct?

Can I be provided with a more formal and a detailed proof ? ( I would like to be as pedantic as possible)

Comment: Formatting tip:  To obtain $f \circ g$, type `$f \circ g$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its simpler.

$(f^{-1}g^{-1})(gf) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}g)f$, since function composition is associative.

Moreover, $f^{-1}(g^{-1}g)f = f^{-1}{\rm id}_Y f = f^{-1}f ={\rm id}_X$.

Furthermore, $(gf)(f^{-1}g^{-1}) = {\rm id}_Z$.

Thus $f^{-1}g^{-1}$ is inverse to $gf$. Since the inverse is uniquely determined, $f^{-1}g^{-1} = (gf)^{-1}$.

Comment: What is meant by '${\rm id}_X$' '${\rm id}_Y $' and  '${\rm id}_Z$' ?

Comment: Identity mappings.

Comment: Why is $f^{-1}{\rm id}_Y f = f^{-1}f$ ?